# How to set environment variables in Azure ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I want to set the environment on my deployments in the ARM-template to guarantee the environment is the same across machines. Is there a way to set environment variables for a virtual machine created with an ARM template?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Windows

You can use a [Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) to invoke [`SETX`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) at deployment time. Add a nested resource to the `resources` array of your VM resource. This example invokes `SETX MyEnvironmentPrefix (environmentPrefix-parameter-value) /m` on the target machine:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
    "type": "extensions",
    "name": "SetEnvironmentVar",
    "comments": "Sets the MyEnvironmentPrefix system env var",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.9",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
            "commandToExecute": "[concat('SETX MyEnvironmentPrefix ', parameters('environmentPrefix'), ' /m')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a direct way to do that (looking at the schema), but you could always implement something custom, [Script extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-customscript) or [DSC extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-dsc-overview).

Comment: Maby we should add a feature request as well. Feels like a useful thing to have.